# Failed Install of SQL Server 2017 Express

Tags: sql, sql-server, installation

A computer I am trying to install SQL Server 2017 Express has never successfully installed and repair doesn't help. I have tried numerous times to uninstall with various uninstallers from MS, the add remove programs in control panel and of course the MS SQL uninstall media. When I try to install SQL Server 2017 with the install media I get the following error:

> The MOF compiler could not connect with the WMI server. This is either because of a semantic error such as an incompatibility with the existing WMI repository or an actual error such as the failure of the WMI server to start.

[image: error1]

When I click 'OK' I get another ERROR right away:

> PerfLib 2.0 counter removal failed with exit code 2. Command line: C:\WINDOWS\system32\unlodctr.exe /m:hkengperfctr.xml from directory C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\140\Shared.

[image: error2]

when I start the SQL Server 2017 Configuration Manager I see the following:

> MMC could not create the snap-in. The snap-in might not have been installed correctly. Name: SQL Server Configuration Manager. CLSID: {11E6488B-29AF-469D-9B9A-7A9048D36999}

[image]

Here are the referenced log files:

This is the sql_engine_core_inst_Cpu64_1 log

```
=== Verbose logging started: 5/21/2019  10:19:10  Build type: SHIP UNICODE 5.00.10011.00  Calling process: C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\140\Setup Bootstrap\SQL2017\x64\ScenarioEngine.exe ===
MSI (c) (68:14) [10:19:10:283]: Resetting cached policy values
MSI (c) (68:14) [10:19:10:283]: Machine policy value 'Debug' is 0
MSI (c) (68:14) [10:19:10:283]: ******* RunEngine:
           ******* Product: C:\Users\aryc\Downloads\SQLEXPRADV_x64_ENU\x64\setup\sql_engine_core_inst.msi
           ******* Action: 
           ******* CommandLine: **********
MSI (c) (68:14) [10:19:10:283]: Client-side and UI is none or basic: Running entire install on the server.
MSI (c) (68:14) [10:19:10:283]: Grabbed execution mutex.
MSI (c) (68:14) [10:19:10:283]: Cloaking enabled.
MSI (c) (68:14) [10:19:10:283]: Attempting to enable all disabled privileges before calling Install on Server
MSI (c) (68:14) [10:19:10:283]: Incrementing counter to disable shutdown. Counter after increment: 0
MSI (s) (00:38) [10:19:10:299]: Running installation inside multi-package transaction C:\Users\aryc\Downloads\SQLEXPRADV_x64_ENU\x64\setup\sql_engine_core_inst.msi
MSI (s) (00:38) [10:19:10:299]: Grabbed execution mutex.
MSI (s) (00:38) [10:19:10:299]: Resetting cached policy values
MSI (s) (00:38) [10:19:10:299]: Machine policy value 'Debug' is 0
MSI (s) (00:38) [10:19:10:299]: ******* RunEngine:
           ******* Product: C:\Users\aryc\Downloads\SQLEXPRADV_x64_ENU\x64\setup\sql_engine_core_inst.msi
           ******* Action: 
           ******* CommandLine: **********
MSI (s) (00:38) [10:19:10:299]: Machine policy value 'TransformsSecure' is 0
MSI (s) (00:38) [10:19:10:299]: User policy value 'TransformsAtSource' is 0
MSI (s) (00:38) [10:19:10:299]: Machine policy value 'DisableUserInstalls' is 0
MSI (s) (00:38) [10:19:10:299]: Specified instance {36C9ADEE-91B0-4FFA-9CBA-9164CE6089D5} via transform :InstID02.mst;:InstName02.mst is already installed. MSINEWINSTANCE requires a new instance that is not installed.
MSI (s) (00:38) [10:19:10:299]: MainEngineThread is returning 1639
MSI (s) (00:38) [10:19:10:299]: User policy value 'DisableRollback' is 0
MSI (s) (00:38) [10:19:10:299]: Machine policy value 'DisableRollback' is 0
MSI (s) (00:38) [10:19:10:299]: Incrementing counter to disable shutdown. Counter after increment: 0
MSI (s) (00:38) [10:19:10:299]: Note: 1: 1402 2: HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Installer\Rollback\Scripts 3: 2 
MSI (s) (00:38) [10:19:10:299]: Note: 1: 1402 2: HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Installer\Rollback\Scripts 3: 2 
MSI (s) (00:38) [10:19:10:299]: Decrementing counter to disable shutdown. If counter >= 0, shutdown will be denied.  Counter after decrement: -1
MSI (c) (68:14) [10:19:10:299]: Decrementing counter to disable shutdown. If counter >= 0, shutdown will be denied.  Counter after decrement: -1
MSI (c) (68:14) [10:19:10:299]: MainEngineThread is returning 1639
=== Verbose logging stopped: 5/21/2019  10:19:10 ===
```

This is the Summary_aryc_20190521_101725 log

```
This is the Summary_aryc_20190521_101725 log

Overall summary:
  Final result:                  Failed: see details below
  Exit code (Decimal):           -2068052377
  Start time:                    2019-05-21 10:17:25
  End time:                      2019-05-21 10:38:21
  Requested action:              Install

Setup completed with required actions for features.
Troubleshooting information for those features:
  Next step for FullText:        Use the following information to resolve the error, and then try the setup process again.
  Next step for SQLEngine:       Use the following information to resolve the error, and then try the setup process again.


Machine Properties:
  Machine name:                  aryc
  Machine processor count:       8
  OS version:                    Microsoft Windows 10 Pro (10.0.17134)
  OS service pack:               
  OS region:                     United States
  OS language:                   English (United States)
  OS architecture:               x64
  Process architecture:          64 Bit
  OS clustered:                  No

Product features discovered:
  Product              Instance             Instance ID                    Feature                                  Language             Edition              Version         Clustered  Configured

Package properties:
  Description:                   Microsoft SQL Server 2017 
  ProductName:                   SQL Server 2017
  Type:                          RTM
  Version:                       14
  SPLevel:                       0
  Installation location:         C:\Users\aryc\Downloads\SQLEXPRADV_x64_ENU\x64\setup\
  Installation edition:          Express

Product Update Status:
  None discovered.

User Input Settings:
  ACTION:                        Install
  ADDCURRENTUSERASSQLADMIN:      true
  AGTSVCACCOUNT:                 NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE
  AGTSVCPASSWORD:                *****
  AGTSVCSTARTUPTYPE:             Disabled
  ASBACKUPDIR:                   Backup
  ASCOLLATION:                   Latin1_General_CI_AS
  ASCONFIGDIR:                   Config
  ASDATADIR:                     Data
  ASLOGDIR:                      Log
  ASPROVIDERMSOLAP:              1
  ASSERVERMODE:                  TABULAR
  ASSVCACCOUNT:                  <empty>
  ASSVCPASSWORD:                 <empty>
  ASSVCSTARTUPTYPE:              Automatic
  ASSYSADMINACCOUNTS:            <empty>
  ASTELSVCACCT:                  <empty>
  ASTELSVCPASSWORD:              <empty>
  ASTELSVCSTARTUPTYPE:           0
  ASTEMPDIR:                     Temp
  BROWSERSVCSTARTUPTYPE:         Disabled
  CLTCTLRNAME:                   <empty>
  CLTRESULTDIR:                  <empty>
  CLTSTARTUPTYPE:                0
  CLTSVCACCOUNT:                 <empty>
  CLTSVCPASSWORD:                <empty>
  CLTWORKINGDIR:                 <empty>
  COMMFABRICENCRYPTION:          0
  COMMFABRICNETWORKLEVEL:        0
  COMMFABRICPORT:                0
  CONFIGURATIONFILE:             
  CTLRSTARTUPTYPE:               0
  CTLRSVCACCOUNT:                <empty>
  CTLRSVCPASSWORD:               <empty>
  CTLRUSERS:                     <empty>
  ENABLERANU:                    true
  ENU:                           true
  EXTSVCACCOUNT:                 <empty>
  EXTSVCPASSWORD:                <empty>
  FEATURES:                      SQLENGINE, FULLTEXT
  FILESTREAMLEVEL:               0
  FILESTREAMSHARENAME:           <empty>
  FTSVCACCOUNT:                  NT Service\MSSQLFDLauncher
  FTSVCPASSWORD:                 <empty>
  HELP:                          false
  IACCEPTPYTHONLICENSETERMS:     false
  IACCEPTROPENLICENSETERMS:      false
  IACCEPTSQLSERVERLICENSETERMS:  true
  INDICATEPROGRESS:              false
  INSTALLSHAREDDIR:              C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\
  INSTALLSHAREDWOWDIR:           C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\
  INSTALLSQLDATADIR:             <empty>
  INSTANCEDIR:                   C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\
  INSTANCEID:                    MSSQLSERVER
  INSTANCENAME:                  MSSQLSERVER
  ISMASTERSVCACCOUNT:            NT AUTHORITY\Network Service
  ISMASTERSVCPASSWORD:           <empty>
  ISMASTERSVCPORT:               8391
  ISMASTERSVCSSLCERTCN:          <empty>
  ISMASTERSVCSTARTUPTYPE:        Automatic
  ISMASTERSVCTHUMBPRINT:         <empty>
  ISSVCACCOUNT:                  NT AUTHORITY\Network Service
  ISSVCPASSWORD:                 <empty>
  ISSVCSTARTUPTYPE:              Automatic
  ISTELSVCACCT:                  <empty>
  ISTELSVCPASSWORD:              <empty>
  ISTELSVCSTARTUPTYPE:           0
  ISWORKERSVCACCOUNT:            NT AUTHORITY\Network Service
  ISWORKERSVCCERT:               <empty>
  ISWORKERSVCMASTER:             <empty>
  ISWORKERSVCPASSWORD:           <empty>
  ISWORKERSVCSTARTUPTYPE:        Automatic
  MATRIXCMBRICKCOMMPORT:         0
  MATRIXCMSERVERNAME:            <empty>
  MATRIXNAME:                    <empty>
  MRCACHEDIRECTORY:              
  NPENABLED:                     0
  PBDMSSVCACCOUNT:               <empty>
  PBDMSSVCPASSWORD:              <empty>
  PBDMSSVCSTARTUPTYPE:           0
  PBENGSVCACCOUNT:               <empty>
  PBENGSVCPASSWORD:              <empty>
  PBENGSVCSTARTUPTYPE:           0
  PBPORTRANGE:                   <empty>
  PBSCALEOUT:                    false
  PID:                           *****
  QUIET:                         false
  QUIETSIMPLE:                   false
  ROLE:                          AllFeatures_WithDefaults
  RSINSTALLMODE:                 DefaultNativeMode
  RSSVCACCOUNT:                  <empty>
  RSSVCPASSWORD:                 <empty>
  RSSVCSTARTUPTYPE:              Automatic
  SAPWD:                         *****
  SECURITYMODE:                  SQL
  SQLBACKUPDIR:                  <empty>
  SQLCOLLATION:                  SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
  SQLSVCACCOUNT:                 NT Service\MSSQLSERVER
  SQLSVCINSTANTFILEINIT:         false
  SQLSVCPASSWORD:                <empty>
  SQLSVCSTARTUPTYPE:             Automatic
  SQLSYSADMINACCOUNTS:           MAINMAN\aryc
  SQLTELSVCACCT:                 NT Service\SQLTELEMETRY
  SQLTELSVCPASSWORD:             <empty>
  SQLTELSVCSTARTUPTYPE:          Automatic
  SQLTEMPDBDIR:                  <empty>
  SQLTEMPDBFILECOUNT:            1
  SQLTEMPDBFILEGROWTH:           64
  SQLTEMPDBFILESIZE:             8
  SQLTEMPDBLOGDIR:               <empty>
  SQLTEMPDBLOGFILEGROWTH:        64
  SQLTEMPDBLOGFILESIZE:          8
  SQLUSERDBDIR:                  <empty>
  SQLUSERDBLOGDIR:               <empty>
  SUPPRESSPRIVACYSTATEMENTNOTICE: false
  TCPENABLED:                    0
  UIMODE:                        AutoAdvance
  UpdateEnabled:                 true
  UpdateSource:                  MU
  USEMICROSOFTUPDATE:            false
  X86:                           false

  Configuration file:            C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\140\Setup Bootstrap\Log\20190521_101725\ConfigurationFile.ini

Detailed results:
  Feature:                       Full-Text and Semantic Extractions for Search
  Status:                        Failed
  Reason for failure:            An error occurred for a dependency of the feature causing the setup process for the feature to fail.
  Next Step:                     Use the following information to resolve the error, and then try the setup process again.
  Component name:                SQL Server Database Engine Services Instance Features
  Component error code:          1639
  Component log file:            C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\140\Setup Bootstrap\Log\20190521_101725\sql_engine_core_inst_Cpu64_1.log
  Error description:             Invalid command line argument. Consult the Windows Installer SDK for detailed command line help.
  Error help link:               https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink?LinkId=20476&ProdName=Microsoft+SQL+Server&EvtSrc=setup.rll&EvtID=50000&ProdVer=14.0.1000.169&EvtType=sql_engine_core_inst.msi%400x162A16FE%400x1639

  Feature:                       Database Engine Services
  Status:                        Failed
  Reason for failure:            An error occurred during the setup process of the feature.
  Next Step:                     Use the following information to resolve the error, and then try the setup process again.
  Component name:                SQL Server Database Engine Services Instance Features
  Component error code:          1639
  Component log file:            C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\140\Setup Bootstrap\Log\20190521_101725\sql_engine_core_inst_Cpu64_1.log
  Error description:             Invalid command line argument. Consult the Windows Installer SDK for detailed command line help.
  Error help link:               https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink?LinkId=20476&ProdName=Microsoft+SQL+Server&EvtSrc=setup.rll&EvtID=50000&ProdVer=14.0.1000.169&EvtType=sql_engine_core_inst.msi%400x162A16FE%400x1639

Rules with failures:

Global rules:

Scenario specific rules:

Rules report file:               C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\140\Setup Bootstrap\Log\20190521_101725\SystemConfigurationCheck_Report.htm
```

Sorry for the large amount of info. I have just read a lot of SO questions where the people answering would like as much info as possible.

**--UPDATE-------------------------**

OK. Here are some more details. Looking around at other articles I found some people referring to a tool called, 'Windows Installer Clean Up.' This tool seems to be deprecated. I figured why not... I downloaded from [here](https://www.techspot.com/downloads/388-windows-installer-cleanup-utility.html) and installed it. Once I ran it it loaded what seemed to be everything that was installed on my machine. I uninstalled EVERYTHING that referenced SQL anywhere in the title. There were TONS of duplicates. I imagine these dups existed because of my many attempts to install/uninstall... Thanks, Microsoft, for having a reliable uninstaller... Please note the sarcasm.

After I did that I removed the MS SQL Server directories in my 'Program Files (x86)' and 'Program Files' directories and restart my machine. I did yet another install of SQL Server. Believe it or not it did not error in the usual place. Instead, it got ALL the way through the install and errored at the last possible moment. Of course, right!!! See screenshot.

> The following error has occurred: Cannot process request because the process (13540) has exited.

[image: error3]

I ran yet another repair and my SQL Instance actually showed up. I did a repair and, here is some interesting news, I can actually open my 'SQL Server 2017 Configuration Manager' without a snap-in error. However, I can not start the Service. I get the typical, 'service took too long to start, please see log' error.

[image]

Here is the new log

```
Overall summary:
Final result:                  Failed: see details below
Exit code (Decimal):           -2068578302
Start time:                    2019-05-21 17:51:21
End time:                      2019-05-21 17:52:53
Requested action:              Repair

Setup completed with required actions for features.
Troubleshooting information for those features:
Next step for FullText:        Use the following information to resolve the error, and then try the setup process again.
Next step for SQLEngine:       Use the following information to resolve the error, and then try the setup process again.


Machine Properties:
Machine name:                  aryc
Machine processor count:       8
OS version:                    Microsoft Windows 10 Pro (10.0.17134)
OS service pack:               
OS region:                     United States
OS language:                   English (United States)
OS architecture:               x64
Process architecture:          64 Bit
OS clustered:                  No

Product features discovered:
Product              Instance             Instance ID                    Feature                                  Language             Edition              Version         Clustered  Configured
SQL Server 2017      MSSQLSERVER          MSSQL14.MSSQLSERVER            Database Engine Services                 1033                 Express Edition      14.0.1000.169   No         Yes       
SQL Server 2017      MSSQLSERVER          MSSQL14.MSSQLSERVER            Full-Text and Semantic Extractions for Search 1033                 Express Edition      14.0.1000.169   No         Yes       

Package properties:
Description:                   Microsoft SQL Server 2017 
ProductName:                   SQL Server 2017
Type:                          RTM
Version:                       14
SPLevel:                       0
Installation location:         C:\mc\Stuff\MSSQL\SQLEXPRADV_x64_ENU\x64\setup\
Installation edition:          Express

User Input Settings:
ACTION:                        Repair
AGTDOMAINGROUP:                <empty>
AGTSVCACCOUNT:                 <empty>
AGTSVCPASSWORD:                <empty>
AGTSVCSTARTUPTYPE:             Manual
ASCONFIGDIR:                   Config
ASSVCACCOUNT:                  <empty>
ASSVCPASSWORD:                 <empty>
ASTELSVCACCT:                  <empty>
ASTELSVCPASSWORD:              <empty>
ASTELSVCSTARTUPTYPE:           0
CLTSTARTUPTYPE:                0
CLTSVCACCOUNT:                 <empty>
CLTSVCPASSWORD:                <empty>
CONFIGURATIONFILE:             
CTLRSTARTUPTYPE:               0
CTLRSVCACCOUNT:                <empty>
CTLRSVCPASSWORD:               <empty>
ENU:                           true
EXTSVCACCOUNT:                 <empty>
EXTSVCPASSWORD:                <empty>
FAILOVERCLUSTERGROUP:          <empty>
FAILOVERCLUSTERNETWORKNAME:    <empty>
FTSVCACCOUNT:                  NT Service\MSSQLFDLauncher
FTSVCPASSWORD:                 <empty>
HELP:                          false
IACCEPTPYTHONLICENSETERMS:     false
IACCEPTROPENLICENSETERMS:      false
INDICATEPROGRESS:              false
INSTANCENAME:                  MSSQLSERVER
ISMASTERSVCACCOUNT:            NT AUTHORITY\Network Service
ISMASTERSVCPASSWORD:           <empty>
ISMASTERSVCPORT:               8391
ISMASTERSVCSSLCERTCN:          <empty>
ISMASTERSVCSTARTUPTYPE:        Automatic
ISMASTERSVCTHUMBPRINT:         <empty>
ISSVCACCOUNT:                  NT AUTHORITY\Network Service
ISSVCPASSWORD:                 <empty>
ISSVCSTARTUPTYPE:              Automatic
ISTELSVCACCT:                  <empty>
ISTELSVCPASSWORD:              <empty>
ISTELSVCSTARTUPTYPE:           0
ISWORKERSVCACCOUNT:            NT AUTHORITY\Network Service
ISWORKERSVCCERT:               <empty>
ISWORKERSVCMASTER:             <empty>
ISWORKERSVCPASSWORD:           <empty>
ISWORKERSVCSTARTUPTYPE:        Automatic
MRCACHEDIRECTORY:              
QUIET:                         false
QUIETSIMPLE:                   false
SQLSVCACCOUNT:                 NT Service\MSSQLSERVER
SQLSVCPASSWORD:                <empty>
SQLTELSVCACCT:                 NT Service\SQLTELEMETRY
SQLTELSVCPASSWORD:             <empty>
SQLTELSVCSTARTUPTYPE:          Automatic
SUPPRESSPRIVACYSTATEMENTNOTICE: false
UIMODE:                        AutoAdvance
X86:                           false

Configuration file:            C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\140\Setup Bootstrap\Log\20190521_175121\ConfigurationFile.ini

Detailed results:
Feature:                       Full-Text and Semantic Extractions for Search
Status:                        Failed
Reason for failure:            An error occurred for a dependency of the feature causing the setup process for the feature to fail.
Next Step:                     Use the following information to resolve the error, and then try the setup process again.
Component name:                SQL Server Database Engine Services Instance Features
Component error code:          0x84B40002
Error description:             The SQL Server feature 'SQL_Engine_Core_Inst' is not in a supported state for repair, as it was never successfully configured. Only features from successful installations can be repaired. To continue, remove the specified SQL Server feature.
Error help link:               https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink?LinkId=20476&ProdName=Microsoft+SQL+Server&EvtSrc=setup.rll&EvtID=50000&ProdVer=14.0.1000.169&EvtType=0x2841E06E%401204%402&EvtType=0x2841E06E%401204%402

Feature:                       Database Engine Services
Status:                        Failed
Reason for failure:            An error occurred during the setup process of the feature.
Next Step:                     Use the following information to resolve the error, and then try the setup process again.
Component name:                SQL Server Database Engine Services Instance Features
Component error code:          0x84B40002
Error description:             The SQL Server feature 'SQL_Engine_Core_Inst' is not in a supported state for repair, as it was never successfully configured. Only features from successful installations can be repaired. To continue, remove the specified SQL Server feature.
Error help link:               https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink?LinkId=20476&ProdName=Microsoft+SQL+Server&EvtSrc=setup.rll&EvtID=50000&ProdVer=14.0.1000.169&EvtType=0x2841E06E%401204%402&EvtType=0x2841E06E%401204%402

Feature:                       SQL Browser
Status:                        Passed

Feature:                       SQL Writer
Status:                        Passed

Feature:                       SQL Client Connectivity
Status:                        Passed

Feature:                       SQL Client Connectivity SDK
Status:                        Passed

Feature:                       Setup Support Files
Status:                        Passed

Rules with failures:

Global rules:

There are no scenario-specific rules.

Rules report file:               C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\140\Setup Bootstrap\Log\20190521_175121\SystemConfigurationCheck_Report.htm
```

Comment: Did you try uninstalling then rebooting and attempting a fresh install?

Comment: You can check following post: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/f0238a20-c422-442a-aa2a-76d617bb6272/ms-sql-server-2008-not-getting-installed-properly-mof-compiler-could-not-connect-with-the-wmi?forum=sqlexpress

Comment: Jen R, Yes. Sorry, I failed to mention that I have tried uninstalling multiple times with both the SQL uninstall media as well as the control panel add remove/repair features. I fear that by performing these actions, it might have messed the install/file system up more. Because, you know, programs don't seem to ACTUALLY uninstall from a windows OS when you uninstall them.

Comment: Piotr, Your link suggestion contains another link claiming to have solved the problem with Server 2008. Regardless, I decided to try it out and unfortunately the 'solution' link is broken and leads to an 'oops' page.  "Possibly the issue was caused by uninstalling from add-remove programs - at any rate, using aaron bertrand's suggestion below fixed the issue. Also of note - I used the local admin for the install.  https://sqlblog.org/2009/02/20/the-xp-sp3-msxml6-sp2-sql-server-debacle

Comment: I had the same problem and finally solved it by **Fresh Start**. It removes all installed software and preserves user files. Luckily, I didn't have to much to reinstall.

Comment: Just completely disabled my firewall hoping that maybe it was blocking an outgoing or incoming connection. No go. Still didn't install.

Answer (score 0):

Providing an answer to my own question. Please see the above question for context as I will not be able to provide a root cause.

1. After downloading the deprecated 'Windows Installer Clean Up' utility, I installed and then ran it and removed EVERYTHING that had SQL in the title.
2. I did another re-install of SQL Server. I did get another error as mentioned, but this time at the very end of the install progress
3. I went into Control Panel -> Programs and Features and seen that 'Microsoft SQL Server 2017 (64 Bit)' was actually in the list. So I uninstalled it. However, at the end of the install it did something it had not done before. It displayed a list of each item that was uninstalled and ALL of the appropriate items were listed. And... I did not get an error. Also, the SQL Configuration manager was also removed. Progress.
4. I removed the SQL Server folders from program files and program files (x86) and did a reinstall of SQL server.
5. The install went swimmingly and I now have a solid, working instance of SQL Server Express.

Again, I have NO CLUE why it did what it did and I have no root cause. I DO, however, have visual studio 2019, upgraded from 2017, installed and I can only surmise that the SQL installations that VS Studio installs conflicted with my attempts to install SQL Server Express.

Answer (score 0):

I got the -2068578302 error code when running an unattended install of SQL Server 2022 Developer Edition.

**This is what was being ran:**

```
"F:\setup.exe" /IAcceptSqlServerLicenseTerms /Q /ConfigurationFile="c:\Windows\Temp\SQL2022ConfigFile.ini"
```

**The SQL2022ConfigFile.ini included:**

```
; Setup will not display any user interface. 

QUIET="False"

; Setup will display progress only, without any user interaction. 

QUIETSIMPLE="True"
```

**Making the settings in the file consistent with /Q resolved the issue:**

```
; Setup will not display any user interface. 

QUIET="True"

; Setup will display progress only, without any user interaction. 

QUIETSIMPLE="False"
```